# How to judge the ourermost layer of div lose cursor?

Tags: javascript, cursor

here is my question. Please read the below code first.

```
<div id="outerDiv">
<input id="txt" type="text" />
<div id="innerDiv" style="display:none;z-index:10;">
    some content
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is that the inner div shows when the cursor focus into the input and hide if the cursor is out of the outer div. But the inner div will not be hided if the cursor is on the inner div. I want to make it out by binding functions that controll the visibility of the inner div to the focus and focusout event of the input, but I failed. Because I can't make sure where the cursor is with the focusout event function of input. 
Am I make the question clear? Thx in advince.
Here is the javascript code I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var outerDiv = $("#outerDiv");
    var innerDiv = $("#innerDiv");
    var txt = $("#txt");
    txt.focus(function () { innerDiv.show(); });
    outerDiv.focusout(function () { innerDiv.hide(); });
})
</script>
```

What I do not expext is when clicking the text in the inner div, it will not disappear. Anyone has come across the same problem?

Comment: can you please show me the javascript code you used?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on this website, I am not familiar with it yet. I will upload my code asap.

Comment: You did not provide any javascript :(

Comment: javascript code has been uploaded. If you have any time, help me. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that when I click any other place of the page then to close the pop layer innerDiv. If to realize the effect by registing focusout event on the outerDiv, the result is I can't even fire the event on the innerDiv. Because when clicking the elements of the innerDiv, it will firstly fire the focusout event on the outerDiv which is to close the innerDiv. So I realize the effect that I want will not be carried out by simply registing focusout event to the outerDiv.
I did this by registing mouseup event on the document. The function binded to the mouseup event is to find out whether the srcElent is the descendant of the outerDiv, if no then close the innerDiv. The function is some like below:

```
window.onmouseup = function (mouseevt) {
        var srcElement = mouseevt.srcElement;
        while (srcElement != null && srcElement != window) {
            if (srcElement.id== 'outerDiv') {
                return;
            }
            srcElement = srcElement.parentElement;
        }
        hideInnerDiv();
    };
```